# Value return Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, typeerror, angular9

I am super new to angular so I don't know if this been answered. I looked into some answers but couldn't get this right. Sorry if this is already been answered.

I have a Angular service that call backend Rest API

```js
export class StudentService {
    private studentUrl: string;

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
        this.studentUrl = 'someurl';
    }

    public getTag(email: string): Observable < PayLoad > {
        const params = new HttpParams().set("email", email);
        return this.httpClient.get < PayLoad > (this.studentUrl.concat("Tag"), {
            params
        });
    }

    getCoursesForStudent(tag: string): Observable < CourseDto > {
        const params = new HttpParams().set("tag", tag);
        return this.httpClient.get < CourseDto > (this.studentUrl.concat('courses'), {
            params
        })
    }

    getStudentByEmail(email: string): Observable < any > {
        const params = new HttpParams().set("email", email.toString());
        return this.httpClient.get < Student > (this.studentUrl.concat('getstu'), {
            params
        })
    }
}
```

And I also have a component that consume it

```js
export class StudentprofileComponent implements OnInit {
    courses: Observable < CourseDto > ;
    student: Student;
    newstu: Student;
    tag: PayLoad;
    payload = PayLoad;

    constructor(private studentservice: StudentService, private router: Router) {}

    loadCourses() {
        payload: new PayLoad();
        const email = atob(localStorage.getItem('stuemail'));
        this.studentservice.getTag(email).subscribe(data => {
            this.tag = data,
                console.log("data:" + data.value)
        });
        return this.studentservice.getCoursesForStudent(this.tag.value);
    }

    loadStudent() {
        let email = atob(localStorage.getItem('email'));
        return this.studentservice.getStudentByEmail(email.toString());
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadStudent().subscribe(data => {
                this.student = data
            }, error =>
            console.log(error));
        this.courses = this.loadCourses();
    }

}
```

The problem is that, I keep getting **TypeError Cannot read property 'value' of undefined**. Even data is printed in console also.

[image: This is the TypeError]

[image: Error Line]

Comment: You're not getting a proper response for your service call. That makes your 'data' variable undefined. So when you're trying to get a field from an undefined var, you get an error.

Comment: A response  is dispatched from the service call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesting subscriptions is an Anti-pattern and should be avoided. Try using the switchMap operator to get the values you need.

```
export class StudentprofileComponent implements OnInit {
    courses: CourseDto ; // Removed the Observable due to new subscription
    student: Student;
    // newstu: Student;
    // tag: PayLoad;
    // payload = PayLoad;

    constructor(private studentservice: StudentService, private router: Router) {}

    // loadCourses() {
    //     payload: new PayLoad();
    //     const email = atob(localStorage.getItem('stuemail'));
    //     this.studentservice.getTag(email).subscribe(data => {
    //         this.tag = data,
    //             console.log("data:" + data.value)
    //     });
    //     return this.studentservice.getCoursesForStudent(this.tag.value);
    // }

    // loadStudent() {
    //     let email = atob(localStorage.getItem('email'));
    //     return this.studentservice.getStudentByEmail(email.toString());
    // }

    ngOnInit() {
        const email = atob(localStorage.getItem('email')).toString();
        const stuEmail = atob(localStorage.getItem('stuemail')).toString();

        this.studentservice.getStudentByEmail(email).subscribe(student => this.student = student);

        this.studentservice.getTag(stuEmail).pipe(
            switchMap(tag => this.studentservice.getCoursesForStudent(tag.value))
        ).subscribe(courses => this.courses = courses);
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an asynchroun call. You don't know when the server will return the answer to this get-endpoint-

You subscribe on the call with the function .subscribe().
In the moment where you subscribe the get will try to reach the backend.

Everything inside he subscribe function will be executed when the get is returned.

```
//1.register subscription
    this.studentservice.getTag(email).subscribe(
data=>{
//3. will be executed when server answers
this.tag = data , 
    console.log("data:"+data.value)});

//2. Will return the value before the tag-object is set in subscribe
    return this.studentservice.getCoursesForStudent(this.tag.value);
```

So you have the problem that in the moment when you call the line where the return is, the tag object is still undefined, because the subscription has not returned yet.

You could try to execute the getCoursesForStudent inside the subscription, but this will make it more complex.

You could try to use a switchmap to subscribe to the observable when the other is finished
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap